# Get Column Types of Julia DataFrames

Tags: dataframe, types, julia

How can I get the column types of a Julia `DataFrame`?

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(a = 1:4, b = ["a", "b", "c", "d"])

4×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      
     │ Int64  String 
─────┼───────────────
   1 │     1  a
   2 │     2  b
   3 │     3  c
   4 │     4  d
```

Answer (score 6):

Some additional options (keeping the result in a data frame):

```
julia> mapcols(eltype, df)
1×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a         b
     │ DataType  DataType
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ Int64     String

julia> mapcols(typeof, df)
1×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a              b
     │ DataType       DataType
─────┼───────────────────────────────
   1 │ Vector{Int64}  Vector{String}

julia> describe(df, :eltype)
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ variable  eltype
     │ Symbol    DataType
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ a         Int64
   2 │ b         String
```

EDIT: in `describe` you get the element type of a column with stripped `Missing` - I have forgotten to add this comment earlier.

Comment: The last one is so cool and neat.

Comment: I also like the last one a lot. `mapcols` is not my favorite though, because it writes the results in columns and therefore quickly gets truncated.

Comment: I have forgotten to add one catch. `describe` strips `Missing` from element type. This is often wanted (that is the reason for this behavior), but in some cases you might not want it.

Answer (score 3):

For each column I can get the element type like this:

```
eltype.(eachcol(df))
```

The same can be achieved (and I like this even better) with

```
df |> eachcol .|> eltype

2-element Vector{DataType}:
 Int64
 String
```

The actual type of the column can be retrieved with

```
df |> eachcol .|> typeof

2-element Vector{DataType}:
 Vector{Int64} (alias for Array{Int64, 1})
 Vector{String} (alias for Array{String, 1})
```